# Bluetooth dongle causing Wired mouse to stutter

Tags: usb, mouse, bluetooth, wired

I've just got a new office PC. I've plugged in a ASUS USB-BT400 bluetooth dongle so that I can use a set of TaoTronics wireless headphones.

Whenever I play sound over the bluetooth headset, my wired mouse starts to stutter.
I've done a search but the only results I can find on there are to do with wireless mice.

The PC itself is good spec: I7, 500gb SSD, 32gb RAM Win 10 and there's no obvious spike in memory or CPU usage when these spikes occur.

What can be done about this? Is this likely to be specific to this model of Bluetooth dongle or is this more likely to be the same for all USB dongles. Is there anything I can do to fix this short of issue, short of just plugging the headphones in using a headphone lead?

Comment: Try using different USB ports, a different mouse, or a different BT dongle.

Comment: I tried all the USB ports, front Back and the Super Speed ones, nothing makes a difference. In the end I just plugged the headphones in with a aux lead. I think that whatever process is involved in encoding and transmitting sound over the bluetooth dongle puts too much load on the USB controller or something.